# Prometheus, how to convert counter to gauge

Tags: prometheus, counter, metrics, gauge

I’ve a custom metric that change of type in the metric file (mistake from developper).

So I’ve start to scrap metrics as counter, but it is really a gauge.
We have change in the metric file, but prometheus continue as it is a counter.

I’ve try to delete serie like this :

remove scrap from config
restart prometheus
delete serie from api
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match%5B%5D= 1…
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/clean_tombstones 1
restart prometheus
→ data empty, but serie name exists
add scrap to config
restart prometheus
→ new data scrapping, but old counter type and value continue to increment
That work fine to clean data, but the serie stay work as a counter (and it has not reset the counter).

I can’t change the serie name (due to application obligations).

Is it a solution to fully remove a serie (values, history, config, type) and recreate it with a new scrap ?

Thanks

Comment: Hello ! no ideas ???

Comment: I have the exact same issue now, and I'm wondering if you ever managed to do what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your metric with the `increase` function.